# Missing characters in text file, output via VB6

Tags: vb6

When outputting a text file, it randomly (it seems) misses characters.  I have this running on over 3000 sites daily, and roughly 20 sites have it occur on a semi-regular basis.  The file will range from 300kb to 5 meg!  And the position it occurs is not the same, and regenerating the file once the problem is noticed, it will not miss the characters the second time.

The file is created with some incredibly simple vb6 code:

```
intfile = FreeFile
Open wFileName For Output As #intfile
Print #intfile, wContents 
Close #intfile
```

If anyone has any ideas as to what could be causing it, that would be awesome, I'm completely stumped.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Try to delete the output file before `Print`ing to it (if it already exists).

Comment: Is this file on a network location or on a local drive? Are you saying that one `wContents` can encompass 5MB of text? If so have you tried printing one line at a time instead?

Comment: @JimMack it's a local drive, and yes, wContents is the entire contents of the file.  It's a Jason file built in memory so I went the easy route and printed it all at once. The fact it works at the vast majority of locations is what is baffling me, but will try doing it it piecemeal and see if it improves things.

Comment: @wqw the file does not exist prior, and a I do a dir and kill first to be safe.